# Blower Motor Location on my wrangler

Tags: jeep, heater-blower, wrangler

So, was working on my A/C and was trying to find the blower motor. from what I had seen on the internet, for the '99 Wrangler TJ's it is usually located under the glove box. now I did some digging around and found nothing. am I missing something?

*where I was looking*

[image: Under the glovebox]

[image: 2nd view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike most blower motors found under the passenger side dash, your blower motor is accessed through the engine compartment on the passenger side.  There are three bolts holding it in place.  Below is a link on how to replace your blower motor.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL5Bzl2CTis